# Create img from text in datalist or search option then drag and drop to table

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I am looking to create a datalist from a mysql query. Then once a value is selected, create an img which will be dragged and dropped into a table or grid. I found the code listed below from "Someguy" posted a few years back, and it seems like a good start. I want the img being dropped to display the text which was selected in the table / grid.

```
    var tCtx = document.getElementById('textCanvas').getContext('2d'), //Hidden canvas
    imageElem = document.getElementById('image'); //Image element
// Text input element
document.getElementById('textInput').addEventListener('keyup', function (){
    tCtx.canvas.width = tCtx.measureText(this.value).width;
    tCtx.fillText(this.value, 0, 10);
    imageElem.src = tCtx.canvas.toDataURL();
    console.log(imageElem.src);
}, false);
```